# Sed to combine N text lines separated by blank lines?

Tags: sed

I searched a bit, but didn't find a solution for this specific situation.  Given a pipe that outputs groups of an arbitrary number of non-blank lines separated single blank lines, is there a sed one-liner (or awk one-liner or perl one-liner) that will combine the groups of non-blank lines into single lines, while preserving the blank lines?  For example, the input

```
one
two

three
four
five

six

seven
eight
```

should be output as

```
one two

three four five

six

seven eight
```

Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl one-liner

```
perl -00 -lpe 'tr/\n/ /'
```

where

- `-00` reads the input in blank-line-separated paragraphs
- `-l` automatically handles end-of-line newlines
- `-p` automatically prints each record after processing
- `tr/\n/ /'` changes all newlines to spaces

Answer (score 8):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/./{:a;N;s/\n\(.\)/ \1/;ta}' file
```

If the line is not empty read the following line and if that is not empty replace the newline by a space and repeat, otherwise print the pattern space. If the line was empty in the first place print the empty line: this caters for an empty first line, if this is not the case then and there is only one empty line between non-blank lines:

```
 sed ':a;N;s/\n\(.\)/ \1/;ta' file
```

is suffice.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` solution: Set RS to blank line and ORS to two new lines, if you do not wish to have blank lines in output, just remote ORS from below command.

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '{$1=$1}1' foo.in
one two

three four five

six

seven eight
```

Answer (score 3):

Sample input modified to include more than one consecutive blank lines

```
$ cat ip.txt 
one
two


three
four
five

six

seven
eight
```

`awk` solution:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '{gsub("\n"," "); print}' ip.txt 
one two

three four five

six

seven eight
```

To preserve multiple blanks as well:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/[^\n]\K\n(?=^[^\n])/ /mgs' ip.txt 
one two


three four five

six

seven eight
```

- `-0777` will slurp entire file as a string, so not suitable if input file is large enough to not fit in memory
- The regex matches non-newline character followed by newline and next line not being blank line. lookbehind and lookahead are used for easy replacement and avoiding recursive search